# Overriding styles in components from dependency

Tags: css, angular, sass

I'm using ngx-charts library in my angular 2 project. With angular 2 material design I'm wondering how to add a margin-top to the list and also a margin-bottom to the total number.

[Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXuac.png)

[HTML snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d5QLC.png)

```
.invoice-chart {
  height: 350px;

  ngx-charts-advanced-pie-chart div div .advanced-pie-legend-wrapper {
    background-color: red;
  }
```

Comment: Rather than use Angular's styleUrl: system, it is still possible to write standard CSS selectors like ".myApp ngx-chart .header" that don't use Angular's special selector generation (eg, . With enough specificity (enough selectors) they will overwrite the [ng-content_c27] selectors coming from the first type.

Comment: @Katana314 so with the added HTML snippet this SCSS should do the trick of changing background color of the div?

Comment: @Katana314 Actually, if you globally disable `viewEncapsulation`, it will remove the `[ng-content_***]` selectors.

Comment: And if I don't want to to this ... ?

Comment: @BartB It should. Make sure your CSS is declared in a place that is not specific to the context of a component.